# Python requests memory managements in long running script

Tags: python, python-requests

I have a long running script that uses the requests library to load a webpage once every few seconds for a long time, i.e.

```
while True:
   website = "https://example.com"
   data = {"pass": "password", "user": "username"}
   r=requests.post(website,data=data)
   time.sleep(10)
```

When I run this for a long time (several hours) the memory used by the program becomes very high.  I have solved this by restarting the program every hour or so, but I was wondering if there is a better way to manage the memory?

Comment: It appears to occured on other place, i ran the code you provide for 15min but it keeps at `50.30078125MB`(check by `memory_profiler`).